# When dynamically changing theme colourPrimaryDark is not taking effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I have an application which needs to apply different themes on user's choice. So, I have created the themes. These themes are working fine when applied through the **Manifest.xml**. But when I try to programmatically change the themes, only ActionBar colour is getting changed and the status bar colour remains same like the theme I have applied in Manifest.xml. My codes are in below. I already tried all the available resources but failed to find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

**themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!--<Cyan Theme Configuration>-->

    <style name="Theme.Cyan" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_cyan_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_cyan_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_cyan_variant</item>

        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>


    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Cyan.ToolBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_cyan_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_cyan_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_cyan_variant</item>


    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Cyan.ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color_cyan_variant</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_color_dark_cyan_variant</item>

    </style>

    <!--<Blue Theme Configuration>-->

    <style name="Theme.Blue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_blue_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_blue_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_blue_variant</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>


    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Blue.ToolBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_blue_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_blue_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_blue_variant</item>


    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Blue.ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color_blue_variant</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_color_dark_blue_variant</item>

    </style>

    <!--<Teal Theme Configuration>-->

    <style name="Theme.Teal" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_teal_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_teal_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_teal_variant</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>


    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Teal.ToolBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_teal_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_teal_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_teal_variant</item>


    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Teal.ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color_teal_variant</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_color_dark_teal_variant</item>

    </style>

    <!--<Green Theme Configuration>-->

    <style name="Theme.Green" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_green_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_green_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_green_variant</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>


    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Green.ToolBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_green_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_green_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_green_variant</item>


    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Green.ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color_green_variant</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_color_dark_green_variant</item>

    </style>

    <!--<BlueGrey Theme Configuration>-->

    <style name="Theme.BlueGrey" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_blueGrey_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_blueGrey_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_blueGrey_variant</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>


    </style>
    <style name="Theme.BlueGrey.ToolBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_blueGrey_variant</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark_blueGrey_variant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_for_blueGrey_variant</item>


    </style>

    <style name="Theme.BlueGrey.ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color_blueGrey_variant</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_color_dark_blueGrey_variant</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Green">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="Ocean" parent="Theme.Cyan"/>
    <style name="Sky" parent="Theme.Blue"/>
    <style name="Peacock" parent="Theme.Teal"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.Grass" parent="Theme.Green"/>
    <style name="Shadow" parent="Theme.BlueGrey"/>

    <style name="menu_labels_style">
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>-->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:name="com.compassites.employeedirectory.EmployeeDirectoryApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Ocean);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

[image]

Comment: Try restarting activity with new theme.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. I want to change the themes dynamically !!

Comment: http://www.developer.com/ws/android/changing-your-android-apps-theme-dynamically.html

Comment: Show the code how are you changing themes

Comment: @Apurva, It's already there in the ManiActivity.java

Comment: @RobertRowntree, Sorry to say that I've tried this method but it's not the solution I want.

Answer (score 1):

Call set theme before super.onCreate 
i.e.

```
setTheme(R.style.Ocean);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```